# Search for term, wrap it into <span> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some text which I store in variable `$target`:

```
var $target = jQuery(this).text();
```

And the text can be something like:

```
Hello world, attack on titan 進撃の巨人 is amazing!
```

Then I have variable `$term` via:

```
var $term = jQuery(this).prev().text();
```

And it can contain something like:

```
attack on titan
```

In a new variable named `$result`, I want to search `$target` for the content of `$term` and wrap that into `<span>` tags. So in this example, `$result` will be:

```
var $result = 'Hello world, <span>attack on titan</span> 進撃の巨人 is amazing!';
```

A relatively simply request but my aim is performance here. What's the best approach?

Comment: I will start a bounty of 50 points once this is eligible for a quality working solution.

Comment: Here is a working example with actual HTML https://jsbin.com/nayedo/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/013xhtwu/2/)**

Here is a relatively simple approach to this:

```
var $target = "Hello world, attack on titan 進撃の巨人 is amazing!";
var $term = "attack on titan";
var $result;

$result = $target.replace($term, "<span>"+$term+"</span>");

console.log($result); // => Hello world, <span>attack on titan</span> 進撃の巨人 is amazing!
```

What we do is replace the `term` we're looking for in `target` with `term` wrapped in `<span></span>`.

Also, if you're planning on doing this more than once, I suggest you streamline the process and make it a function:

```
var wrapInSpan = function(target, term){
    return target.replace(term, "<span>"+term+"</span>");
}

$result = wrapInSpan($target, $term);

console.log($result); // => Hello world, <span>attack on titan</span> 進撃の巨人 is amazing!
```

**Note:**

It's commonly referred to [bad practice to altar the `prototype` of a native object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice), like in @Michael's solution. If you want to make the solution more modular, I suggest making it into it's own separate function like in my solution instead of tampering with the `String` object.

Comment: This is lovely Nick. Going with this one! Thanks!

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var target="Hello world, attack on titan 進撃の巨人 is amazing!";
var term="attack on titan";

var result=target.replace(term,"<span>"+term+"</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the .indexOf method to search for the $term within the $target.

```
var $target = "this is some cool text";
var $term = "cool";
var $result;
if($target.indexOf($term) != -1) {
    $result = $target.replace($term, "<span>"+$term+"</span>");
}

else {
alert('Not there')
}
```